# CKEDITOR.tools.getindex is not a function

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to upgrade my version of CKEDITOR, from 4.4.1 to 4.5.1. To do so I'm uploading my *build-config.js* to fetch the same plugins as before with the latest ckeditor version.

The problem is that using the download CKEDITOR, whenever I try to use it I get the error CKEDITOR.tools.getindex is not a function. And this error comes from the widget plugin.

In widget/plugin.js file in line #1951 you have:

```
var index = CKEDITOR.tools.getIndex( widgetsRepo._.upcasts, function( element ) {
```

and that is exactly here the problem. Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only idea may be that you haven't upgraded everything correctly.

[`CKEDITOR.tools.getIndex`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-getIndex) was added in 4.5.0. And if the widget plugin tries to access it it means that you upgraded the plugin, but apparently not the core. Additionally, it means that you haven't used the online builder to build the whole package at once, because then the core would be concatenated with all the plugins and there could be no problem with different versions being deployed.

Therefore, try from scratch. Build a package containing all plugins that you need, unpack everything to a new directory to avoid problems with write access and similar, and all should be fine.